chromedp golang screenshot not rendering exact html
I want to take a screenshot with chromedp of an element that is in html page. But the result is not the same as the render in a browser
Here is my code. I use httpest to render the page, then chromedp scrap it.
func main() {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte(`<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
                <style>
                        @font-face {
                                font-family: Roboto;
                                src: url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Me5WZLCzYlKw.ttf');
                        }
                        body{
                            background-color:black;                         
                        }
        
                        .text {
                                font-family: Roboto;
                                display: flex;
                                flex-direction: row;
                                align-items: center;
                                background-color: #00000000;
                                width: 178px;
                                height: 29px; 
                                font-size: 24px;
                                text-align: center;
                                line-height: 1;
                        }
        
                        .inner-text {
                                color: #ffffffff;
                                padding: 0px;
        
        
                        }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div class="text">
                        <p class="inner-text">je teste pour voir</p>
                </div>
        </body>
        </html>`))
    }))

    defer ts.Close()

    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    var raw []byte
    err := chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.Tasks{
        chromedp.Navigate(ts.URL),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            // This is done in an ActionFunc because it is reset at each navigate.
            err := emulation.SetDefaultBackgroundColorOverride().WithColor(&cdp.RGBA{R: 0, G: 0, B: 0, A: 0}).Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            return nil
        }),
        chromedp.Screenshot("div.text", &raw, chromedp.NodeVisible),
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = os.WriteFile("image.png", raw, 0o777)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }


}

Here is the result in a web-browser:
what I want:(https://i.sstatic.net/ymg47G0w.png)
what I got: (https://i.sstatic.net/OlBKMzD1.png)
can someone help me ?
EDIT: I've tested whith "headless, false". This time, image is perfect. I really don't know what's wrong
